# Issues getting records between 2 dates(timestamp)

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I am trying to count number of records per month.

Issues :

1.If i try to count number of records from(mm/dd/yyyy) `01/01/2015` to `03/02/2015` , it only shows records from Feb (2) and march (3) some how truncating Jan (1).

2.If i try to search from 12/01/2014 to 03/02/2015 query is not displaying any output. my table and query.

I have checked db it has records form month of December and January .

```
Table : works

work_id | desc | create_date (timestamp)  


SELECT count(`work_id`) as tot
    , MONTH(`create_date`)  as mon
FROM `works`
WHERE  bus_id_fk ="'. $_SESSION['bus_id_fk'].'"
    and  DATE_FORMAT(`create_date`,"%m/%d/%Y") BETWEEN "'.  $sd .'" AND "'.  $ed .'"
GROUP BY YEAR(create_date), MONTH(create_date)

NB: $sd = start date, $ed = end date
```

Comment: why a `dateformat` ? remove dataformat and try to comparewith simple `create_date`. also what is datatype of `startdate` and `enddate`

Comment: $sd and $ed is user input in the form of `mm/dd/yyyy` hence `dateformat`

Comment: if you have datatype as datetime then no need of formatting it while comparing

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it this way:

```
SELECT count(`work_id`) as tot
    , MONTH(`create_date`)  as mon
FROM `works`
WHERE  bus_id_fk ="'. $_SESSION['bus_id_fk'].'"
GROUP BY YEAR(create_date), MONTH(create_date)
```

You will still have gaps,  that is, months without a record, but in those cases the count is 0.

Comment: I need to have values between 2 dates, your code will pull records from all years and all months